# Office 365 unified API (preview) - create distribution group

Tags: office365api

When creating a group in the unified API, it assigns our other domain.  The code below assigns the name *tgr@FuseFX.onmicrosoft.com* instead of *tgr@fusefx.com* (*fusefx.com* is our default domain, and we can't remove the onmicrosoft one.)

Is there anything that I need to specify to force it to use the proper domain, or is this a bug?

---

*POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/fusefx.com/groups*

*Content-Type: application/json*

```
{
    "groupTypes": ["Unified"],
    "description": "Test Group",
    "displayName": "Test Group",
    "mailNickname": "tgr",
    "mailEnabled": "true",
    "securityEnabled": "true"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that after creating the record, you can do a PATCH to update the EmailAddress, even though you can't specify this when initially creating the record.  It might take several minutes to reflect this in Office 365.

So:

```
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/contoso.com/groups('c75831bd-fad3-4191-9a66-280a48528679')

Content-Type: application/json

{
    "EmailAddress": "tgr@fusefx.com"
}
```

Comment: 1.  You have to wait at least 5 seconds before issuing a PATCH - otherwise it will not find the newly created group to change this setting.

Comment: 2.  If you remove a group and then re-add it soon, there's a good chance that it'll add numbers to your email address, i.e. tgr2@fusefx.com.